# How to auto populate system path for default maven local repo for pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use `Maven` offline and I created a local maven repo according to this blog:

http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/04/running-maven-offline-using-local.html

and after `Maven` install my dependencies from online once I am able to locate a folder with all the `jar` files in their respective default sub folder path.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/Users/username/.m2/repository/kaptcha/kaptcha/2.3/kaptcha.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

as an example, now in order to refer my `jar` from local offline `Maven` repo, I have to open a explorer and manually find the path and put them in the `systempath` tag in `pom.xml` for each dependency.

Is there a faster way to do that for multiple dependencies?

I am using just the default folder path for each of the packages that `Maven` downloads to its local repo folder, but some times it is:

`packagename/packagename/version/packagename-version.jar`,

and other times it is:

```
packagename/subpackagename/version/packagename-version.jar
```

such as:

`/Users/username/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/3.2.4/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar`

so it is taking forever to go through them by hand.

Any suggestion appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Systempath is very outdated. Using Maven completely offline is not recommended and will usually not work properly. If you are inside a company, use a Nexus/Artifactory server to proxy the outside world (so that your computer does not need an internet connection).

Comment: When maven build is going on, its downloads the dependencies into the `.m2` home folder and further build will first try to load from that `m2` home or local repository and if not found, it will go for either central or remote repository in search of dependencies.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

If you want `3`-rd party jar to load the project, which are not hosted in `maven` central, here is the guide for the same.

Comment: thanks, so so long as I have the jar already in /Users/username/.m2/repository/ folder after the first maven build, I would be able to use maven build offline without pom xml change since it will look for the local jar first before trying to go to maven central?

Comment: @echo, also you can [install your project into Maven local repository](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-your-project-into-maven-local-repository/) as one of existing options.

Comment: @echo, the build time while loading the project with same dependency, it loads faster than before

coming to the question that you specified, to load the jar from the .m2 repository, I think you just need to specify the groupId and artifectId in the dependencies section of the pom file, if maven can see the dependency it will automatically load.

Or else you can install the 3rd party jar using the command available in the link which I shared earlier